If Aggregate Root needs to check the database, can it have the injection?
public class Lead : FullCompanyEntity<int>, IAggregateRoot
{
    private string? _phone;
    private string? _email;
    private Address? _address;
    public int RecordKeeperId { get; private set; }
    public string LeadCode { get; private set; }
    public int LaedTypeId { get; private set; }
    public LeadStatus Status { get; private set; }
    public int? SaleId { get; private set; }
    public bool SaleHasBeenCompleted { get; private set; }
    public string FirstName { get; private set; }
    public string LastName { get; private set; }
    public string FullName { get; private set; }
    public string? Phone
    {
        get => _phone; set
        {
            if (value.IsNullOrEmptyOrWhiteSpace())
            {
                _phone = null;
                return;
            }
            _phone = value;
        }
    }
    public string? Email
    {
        get => _email; set
        {
            if (value.IsNullOrEmptyOrWhiteSpace())
            {
                _email = null;
                return;
            }
            _email = value;
        }
    }
    public bool IsOpen { get; private set; }
    public DateTime? ClosedAt { get; private set; }
    public Address? Address
    {
        get => _address; set
        {
            if (value is null)
            {
                _address = null;
                return;
            }
            _address = value;
        }
    }

    private readonly List<LeadActivity> _leadActivities = [];
    public IReadOnlyCollection<LeadActivity> LeadActivities => _leadActivities.AsReadOnly();

    private readonly List<Appointment> _appointments = [];
    public IReadOnlyCollection<Appointment> Appointments => _appointments.AsReadOnly();
    private Lead() { }

    public Lead(int recordKeeperId,
                int laedTypeId,
                string firstName,
                string lastName,
                int companyId,
                int importerId,
                int organisationId,
                int distributorId,
                LeadStatus status = LeadStatus.New) : base(companyId, importerId, organisationId, distributorId)
    {
        Guard.Against.NegativeOrZero(recordKeeperId, nameof(recordKeeperId));
        Guard.Against.NegativeOrZero(laedTypeId, nameof(laedTypeId));
        Guard.Against.NullOrWhiteSpace(firstName, nameof(firstName));
        Guard.Against.NullOrWhiteSpace(lastName, nameof(lastName));

        RecordKeeperId = recordKeeperId;
        LaedTypeId = laedTypeId;
        Status = status;
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        FullName = firstName.FullName(lastName);

        LeadCode = "".GenerateUniqueRandomCode(prefix: "LL");
        SaleHasBeenCompleted = false;
        SaleId = null;
        IsOpen = true;
        Status = status;
    }

    public void AssignToExitsSale(Sale sale, ILeadPolicy leadPolicy)
    {
        Guard.Against.Null(sale);

        leadPolicy.HasBeenUsedSaleIdInAnotherLead(sale.Id);

        Status = LeadStatus.Sold;
        SaleHasBeenCompleted = true;
        SaleId = sale.Id;
    }
}

Policy:
public interface ILeadPolicy
{
    bool HasBeenUsedSaleIdInAnotherLead(int saleId);
}

public class LeadPolicy : ILeadPolicy
{
    // todo inject lead repository for reading database
    public bool HasBeenUsedSaleIdInAnotherLead(int saleId)
    {

        // todo check database 
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}


I have an aggregate root as shown above
As far as I understand from my research, an AggregateRoot must decide and control all business rules that concern in it.
When we look at the example above, I am faced with a few problems.
For example, for the lead AggregateRoot above, a lead can only be assigned to one sale and only one lead can be assigned to one sale.
In short, if the same sale has been assigned to another lead before, this should not be allowed.
Of course, I definitely need to connect to the database to check this.
first option;
Write a method in the lead's repository and check the application layer with it. If it passes the check, AssignToExitsSale(without policy) method
Assign sale and lead to each other.
second option;
policy injection in the application layer and calling the AssignToExitsSale(with policy parameter) method
Of course, there are other ways, such as injecting policy in a LeadManager class and doing the assign operation through the manager.
The other problem is; For other AggregateRoots I have, I may need to go to the database and check the in ctor they have. In such a case, I need to pass a policy parameter in ctor.
This may cause problems when mapping (automapper or helping extentions method) from a request dto or another problems

Question )
Can an Aggregate Root database repository injector inject a policy?
Question )
If a structure that does this kind of database validation does not have a database policy within Aggregate Root, wouldn't the business rule be out of control?
Question )
If I need to call multiple AssignToExitsSale methods in different places, then I need to connect to the database and check each time before calling this method,
Wouldn't this create a business rule that could be forgotten or ignored?
Question )
If it is correct to use policy in Aggregate Root, including its use in ctor, then how should I deal with the problems that occur while mapping?

Another business rule control structure I found;

public interface IBusinessRule
{
    bool IsBroken();

    string Message { get; }
}

public class OneSaleIdMustBelongToOneLead : IBusinessRule
{
    public string Message => "A sales ID can only belong to one lead";

    private readonly ILeadPolicy _policy;
    private readonly int _saleId;
    public OneSaleIdMustBelongToOneLead(int saleId, ILeadPolicy policy)
    {
        _policy = policy;
        _saleId = saleId;
    }
    public bool IsBroken()
    {
        return _policy.HasBeenUsedSaleIdInAnotherLead(_saleId);
    }
}


public void AssignToExitsSale(Sale sale, ILeadPolicy leadPolicy)
{
   Guard.Against.Null(sale);

   CheckRule(new OneSaleIdMustBelongToOneLead(sale.Id, leadPolicy));

   //leadPolicy.HasBeenUsedSaleIdInAnotherLead(sale.Id);

   Status = LeadStatus.Sold;
   SaleHasBeenCompleted = true;
   SaleId = sale.Id;
}

However, taking the OneSaleIdMustBelongToOneLead policy parameter here still creates the same problem.
